# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, xml, string

I keep getting the following error for the code below:

```
   AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

for elem in tree_xml.iter():
    if elem.tag.split('}')[1] == elementName:
                found = True
                break
```

Comment: `elem.tag` is a function.

Comment: Where does `tree_xml` come from? You could add a print before the line with the split. `print(type(elem.tag), hasattr(elem.tag, "__name__") and elem.tag.__name__)`. Get a better feel for what it is.

Comment: Even just `print(elem.tag)` would help. Is this ElementTree? If so, `tag` should be a `str`. But its not. Maybe you had some previous code the incorrectly assigned something else to tag.

Comment: I'm guessing that earlier in the code you did something like `elem.tag = str`, and because you forgot the parentheses on the end, elem.tag was assigned to a _function object_ instead of the function _result_.